# Existing big Sybase db and flyway

Tags: database, continuous-integration, sybase, sap-ase, flyway

I have very very big production Sybase DB.
Currently we have custom script that is handling migrations for us.

We are going to introduce `Liquibase` or `Flyway` and check how it will work for us.
Firstly we decided to try with `Flyway` as it is simpler at first glance. 
I was digging around but didn't find any usefull thing.

My question is: Is it possible to use `Flyway` withouth doing dump of current db? DB is very very big and we want to minimalise operational risk.

Comment: Its sybase relational db. Version above 12.

Comment: This is my db version: ASE 15.70.

Comment: What do you mean by "migration"? Migrating from ASE15.7 to another database?

Comment: No, by `Migration` I mean upgrades from one version to another applying proper changes.

Comment: Not sure to follow. If you upgrade ASE from one version let's say 15.5 to 15.7, why will you use liquibase to track the changes as the ASE installer will do everything for you? If you change the db data, liquibase will be interesting to track the changes, right?

Comment: I will use liquibase

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, in general it is possible to do that. But unfortunatelly `Sybase` is not supported by `Flyway` and basically speaking is saying this clearly if you try to run it with sybase.

I will use `liquibase`. 
There were some threads in `Flyway` github but `Sybase` support hasn't been released yet.